# How to split text into words but keep phrases in double quotes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am **trying to convert/differentiate the input**, but it is not working.

this is **input** - "on time" "flight"  and I need to create an **output** like this - ""ON TIME"FLIGHT"

**The Algo** is whenever you find a phrase in double quotes you must convert that as  ""phrase
and single word should be  "word".

**code** :

```
const _searchKeyword = req.body.fullTextKeyword;
 const keywords = _searchKeyword.split(' ');

 
const formattedKeywords = keywords.map(keyword => {
  if (keyword.startsWith('"') && keyword.endsWith('"')) {
    // Phrase within double quotes
    const phrase = keyword.slice(1, -1);
    return `\\"${phrase}\\"`;
  } else {
    // Single word
    return keyword;
  }
});

// Join the escaped words with a space.
let concatenatedKeywords = formattedKeywords.join(" ");
```

but the above **code gave me output like this** - ""on time" \"flight\""

How Will I create output like this, any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const _searchKeyword = 'on time "flight"';
const keywords = _searchKeyword.split(' ');

const formattedKeywords = keywords.map(keyword => {
  if (keyword.startsWith('"') && keyword.endsWith('"')) {
    // Phrase within double quotes
    const phrase = keyword.slice(1, -1);
    return `""${phrase}"`;
  } else {
    // Single word
    return `"${keyword}"`;
  }
});

// Join the formatted words with a space.
const concatenatedKeywords = formattedKeywords.join(' ');

console.log(concatenatedKeywords); // ""on time" "flight""
```

1. For phrases within double quotes, I used "" instead of \" to
   enclose the phrase.
2. For single words, I added quotes " around the keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you should create some string parser here. A simple parser would be in most cases, a [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

In our case we could operate in 2 modes (states), `word` or `phrase` (inside quotes):

```js
const myStr = '    "hello guys", some     words with "quotes inside"" some spaces inside " please keep quoted words as one "phrase / word" end-of-line ';

// has a non closed quote
const myWrongStr = '"hello guys", some words" with "quotes inside" please keep quoted words as one "phrase / word" ';

console.log(myStr+ ':');
console.log(splitToWordsWithQuotes(myStr));
console.log('\n'+myWrongStr+':');
console.log(splitToWordsWithQuotes(myWrongStr));

function splitToWordsWithQuotes(str) {

    let mode;
    const words = [];
    let word = '';

    const completeWord = () => word && words.push(word) && (word = '');

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        const c = str[i];

        if (!mode) {
            if (c === ' ') {
                continue;
            }
            if (c === '"') {
                mode = 'phrase';
            } else {
                word += c;
                mode = 'word';
            }
            continue;
        }

        if (c === '"') {
            completeWord();
            mode = mode === 'word' ? 'phrase' : 'word';
            continue;
        }

        if (c === ' ') {
            if (mode === 'phrase') {
                word += ' ';
                continue;
            }
            completeWord();
            continue;
        }

        word += c;

    }

    completeWord();

    return words;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the final output, I have taken a string and split it up into an array of words using the mixedQuotedString variable.
Now, as I iterate through the array if the string contained a " quote and a " immediately following it, I push it to the output array as is; however, if it didn't, I store it in a variable and continued concatenating the words until I found one that contained a ", at which point I pushed the entire word to the output array.

```js
//Required Variable Declaration
let mixedQuotedString = '"hello guys" some words are "placed in double quotes" keep them together';
let qouteSeperatedArray = mixedQuotedString.split(" ");
let outputArray = []
let tempWord = '';
let isWordContinue = 0;

//Loop to Seperate Words
qouteSeperatedArray.map((qsa, index) => {
  if (qsa.startsWith('"') && qsa.endsWith('"')) {
    outputArray.push(wa.substring(1, qsa.length - 1));
  } else if (qsa.startsWith('"')) {
    tempWord = tempWord.concat('', qsa);
    isWordContinue = 1;
  } else if (qsa.endsWith('"')) {
    tempWord = tempWord.concat(' ', qsa);
    outputArray.push(tempWord.substring(1, tempWord.length - 1));
    tempWord = '';
    isWordContinue = 0;
  } else {
    if (isWordContinue) {
      tempWord = tempWord.concat(' ', qsa);
    } else {
      outputArray.push(qsa);
    }
  }
})
console.log(outputArray)
```

This is the most simplified solution I came up with.

Comment: It is recommended that you explain the code either via explanation or directly inside comments (prior much preferred). Code only answers are usually frowned upon. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer